# jquery ajax post multi dimensional array to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having a download as csv button for exporting the results as csv. Till now I was using server side code for this. I was sending the selected DropDowns Ids to csvdownload.php page which is writing the results in excel.

BUT NOW, I want a utility for selecting the search results using checkbox and then the selected results should written to the csv.

I am planning to get the table data in array and then post it to php using ajax, then it will do the rest of things. But how is this possible to post multiple rows of data to php. **I have following piece of code for getting the table data which is alerting data but dont know how to make it as array and pass to php**

```
      $('#tblSearchResults tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {
     $tr = $(this);
       //alert($tr.find("td").eq(4).html());

        var risk_cat = $tr.find("td").eq(1).html();
        var risk_type = $tr.find("td").eq(2).html();
        var risk_desc = $tr.find("td").eq(3).html();
        var treat_desc = $tr.find("td").eq(4).html();
        var treat_cat = $tr.find("td").eq(5).html();

        selectedData.push({"risk_cat": risk_cat, "risk_type": risk_type, "risk_desc": risk_desc, "treat_desc": treat_desc, "treat_cat": treat_cat});
```

thanks

Comment: You should take a look at `JSON`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use `JSON.stringify(selectedData)` in order to use it on the serverside.

jQuery:

```
var obj = { 'risk_cat': risk_cat, 'risk_type': risk_type };
selectedData.push(obj);

$.post('serive.php', { DTO: JSON.stringify(selectedData) }, 
function(data){ /* handle response,  */ });
```

---

service.php:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');

$foo = json_decode($_POST['DTO']);


$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5); //example data

echo json_encode($arr);
```

This should get you started. In your ajax reponse, `alert(data.a)` would be alerting "1"

Comment: Ok Johan going to try the same

Comment: Hi Johan , thanks again for this help. :) I am posting and getting them.Previsouly I was opening a pop up for writing and outputing a csv file to user. How is this possible now. I mean now I am hitting using ajax.

Comment: @vikassharma You need to handle the response from your sevice.php. Its located in my example at "handle response". `data` is the object that you want to manipulate. Convert the data that you want to send using `json_encode()`, ive updated my example a bit

Comment: yes you are right. But I want to ask how can i output the csv file as downloadable to user. Now, After your answer I am getting the data ,but how can i make the php file downlnoadable to user. previuosly i was not posting data but opening window.location = script.php?data and fputcsv to make csv. but now it is going through post..but not outputing as downloadable csv..please help if you are getting me....

Answer (score 0):

You should use jQuery serialize (http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Create a `<form>` in your page containing `<input>` fields with the values you want to pass to your server.

You would then call your server with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: yourForm.serialize(),
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Comment: thanks for replying pgratton, actually i am getting search results the field above mentioned symbolize one row of search result , i can have multiple rows. I need to post it together having relation between them so that I can fetch at php page and can create a csv..

Comment: you should then take a look at @Johan answer

Answer (score 0):

Check out Jquery forms. You can wrap your table in a form element and It'll post it up serialise with Ajax. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: yourscript.php,
  data: JSON.stringify(selectedData),
  success: function(..){

  },
  contentType: "application/json"
});
```

In your PHP file, read the JSON string from stdin, and use `json_decode` to decode the JSON.

```
$requestObject = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: thanks for replying. I thing that will resolve my problem. going to try this. short question, should i need to sent it like ?selecteddata= json.stringfy(selectedData) so that it can be helpfull in fetching